# Looking for instruction manual for brick set #1845 (20th Anniversary Jackpot)

Tags: instructions

I've done a ton of searching and am unable to find the instructions for lego set #1845  (20th Anniversary Jackpot). I found a ton of sites that list out all of the parts, but none of them seem to have a reference to the actual instructions. I'm wondering if anyone knows of a site that has the manual for this set (for free).

Here are a bunch of links that don't have a link to the manual.

- https://oldlego.com/encyclopedia/items/1845-20th-anniversary-jac_1250.php
- https://store-mp.librick.com/item/view?id=i_1845-1
- https://www.toysperiod.com/lego-set-reference/universal-building-set/basic-set/lego-1845-20th-anniversary-jackpot-blue-bucket/
- http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/1845-1
- http://bricks.argz.com/set/1845-1
- https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=1845-1
- http://brickset.com/sets/1845-1/20th-Anniversary-Jackpot-Bucket
- https://rebrickable.com/sets/1845-1/20th-anniversary-jackpot-bucket-basic-set-1993
- http://en.brickimedia.org/wiki/1845_20th_Anniversary_Jackpot_Bucket

Comment: Are you sure there are instructions? It looks like a loose set of bricks with no specific model to build

Comment: I don't think that the book utilized all of the bricks in the set, but there were definitely instructions that used at least some of the bricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the part number on the instruction book is not the same as the one in my question, it appears that the instructions are exactly the same for both sets.

http://lego.brickinstructions.com/en/lego_instructions/set/1880/rb

Answer (score 2):

I've looked at [letsbuilditagain.com](http://letsbuilditagain.com), [lego.brickinstructions.com](http://lego.brickinstructions.com) and [worldbricks.com](http://worldbricks.com) (you didn't list these sites) and none of them have this set in their catalog, even though they cover many sets from 1993. [Bricklink has these instructions starting at $0.75 plus shipping](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?I=1845-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D) - since it's a booklet this shouldn't set you back more than $3-4 to get a copy.